# How to calculate the distance from $X^2$ to $\operatorname{span}(1,X)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, metric-spaces, inner-products, bilinear-form

***Question:***

Let $E = \Bbb{R}_2[X]$ an euclidian space with a dot product $\left\langle P,Q\right\rangle \ = \int^1_0 {P(t)Q(t)dt}$.

Calculate the distance from $X^2$ to $\operatorname{span}(1,X)$.

---

***Answer:***

Let $(a,b) \in \Bbb{R}^2$. $p$ is the orthogonal projector. We have:

\begin{equation}
a + bX = p^\perp_{\operatorname{span}(1,X)}(X^2) \iff
  \left\{\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
    \langle X^2 - (a+bX), 1\rangle = 0\\
    \langle X^2 - (a+bX), X\rangle = 0\\
  \end{array}\right.\,
\iff
  \left\{\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
    a = -1/6\\
    b = 1\\
  \end{array}\right.\,.
\end{equation}

So the wanted distance is $\left\|X^2-(X-1/6)\right\| = \frac{1}{6\sqrt 5}$.

---

I am a little bit lost since I don't understand how $X^2$ can be projected on $\operatorname{span}(1, X)$.

Since $X^2$ is not a linear combination of $\operatorname{span}(1, X)$.

- Why $a + bX$ is not equal to zero?
- How the dot products $\langle X^2 - (a+bX), 1\rangle \ = 0$ and $\langle X^2 - (a+bX), X\rangle \ = 0$ helps to get the projector? It means that we need to gets $a$ and $b$ where $\left[X^2 - (a+bX)\right] \perp 1$, why?

I would like to have great explanations (like if I didn't have the answer).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Think about $\mathbb R^3$ for a moment. Suppose you have a plane $P$ spanned by two vectors $u, v$ and you have a third vector $w$ which is *not* in the plane but is also *not* orthogonal to the plane. Then it makes sense to project $w$ onto the plane, right? But $w$ is not a linear combination of $u$ and $v$ because $w$ is not contained in the plane. It's the same idea here: as long as $X^2$ is not orthogonal to $\mathrm{span}\{1, X\}$ then $X^2$ has a non-zero projection onto that plane.

Now what does "orthogonal projection" mean? It means precisely  the point $s = p^\perp_P(w)$ contained in $P = \mathrm{span}\{u,v\}$ such that the line from $s$ to $w$ is orthogonal to $P$. "The line from $s$ to $w$" is parallel to the vector $w - s$, so that means
$$
  \langle w-s, u\rangle = 0\quad \langle w-s, v\rangle = 0
\tag{$*$}
$$
because $u,v \in P$.

Now apply this when $u = 1$, $v = X$, and $w = X^2$. What the answer does is write $s = a + bX$ for some unknown scalars $a, b$; we can do this because $s \in P = \mathrm{span}\{1, X\}$. Then the equations ($*$) above give us two linear equations for the unknowns $a, b$ which we can then solve. This gives us the orthogonal projection $s = p^\perp_P(X^2)$, and finally the distance between $X^2$ and $P$ is defined to be the distance between $X^2$ and $s$, which is $||X^2 - s||$.

Comment: Good job (+1). I was about to start typing something along these lines. Thanks for saving me the trouble :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanations and the drawing by @Stéphane Jaouen, I understand better, I will study your answer and try to understand perfectly.

Comment: I can show you a calculation or two if you want, it's up to you to finish the exercise.

Comment: I would appreciate @StéphaneJaouen :)

Answer (score 3):

Not much to add to @Nicolas Todoroff. Maybe a drawing that will save OP from possible difficulties with his imagination... :)
[image]

---

As the answers have already been given, the following calculations are to help OP complete his exercise:

As @Nicolas explained, we need to have $X^2-(bX+a)$ orthogonal to $\color{grey}{span(}\color{red}1,\color{green}X\color{grey})$, ie $$\langle X^2-bX-a,\color{red}1\rangle=0 $$ for example.
This is equal to $$\int_{0}^{1}(t^2-bt-a)\color{red}1dt=\frac{1}{3}-\frac b2-a=0$$
Hence $$3b+6a=2 $$

Then $$\langle X^2-bX-a,\color{green}X\rangle=0 \iff 6a+4b=3$$
Thus, $$\begin{cases} 6a+3b=2\\6a+4b=3   \end{cases} \iff \begin{cases} a=\frac{-1}6\\b=1   \end{cases}$$